# Use wget for these kind of links

Tags: wget

How to use wget for these kind of links

https://cloclo28.datacloudmail.ru/weblink/view/7QmV/zjoCdoPY6?etag=8032FAE65E2F49A2BE63ABE5260761CE66491877&key=917d6cbb6d88065d48c52d2602a5d1b77b6bf978

This is a file when download using chrome. But with wget it shows resource unavailable(404).

Comment: Doesn't download either with firefox and noscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many sites do not like their content scraped, so they decline to give it to wget or curl.

You can use the `--user-agent` option to make wget seem more like another browser.

Sometimes cookies are involved.  And referrer headers,  So there is no universal solution.

I find using the text mode browser `lynx` simpler to deal with.  Just save the link from in there.